# How can I save the tags along with the text in tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tags, save, dump

I am creating a text editor using tkinter but when the file is saved the tags disappear.
This is the code for saving the file, opening a file and the function of tagging. I read that in order to make the tags remain I should use dump() but i cannot understand where to put it or how it works. Should it be inside one of these three functions? And how can I connect it to their content?:

```
def open_file(self):
    open_return=filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/", title='Select File to open',
                                        filetypes= (("text files", "*.txt"),("all files", "*.*")))

    if (open_return !=None):
        self.text_area.delete(1.0, END)
        for line in open_return:
            self.text_area.insert(END, line)
        self.__file=open_return.name
        open_return.close()
def save_file(self):
    if self.__file== None:
        # Save as new file
        self.__file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt',
                                        defaultextension=".txt",
                                        filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),
                                            ("Text Documents","*.txt")])

        if self.__file == "":
            self.__file = None
        else:


            file = open(self.__file,"w")
            file.write(self.text_area.get(1.0,END))
            file.close()


            self.master.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notes")


    else:
        file = open(self.__file,"w")
        file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0,END))
        file.close()
def OnGreen(self):
    #With this function I highlight the selected text
    current_tags = self.text_area.tag_names("sel.first")
    if "p" in current_tags:
        self.text_area.tag_remove("p", "sel.first", "sel.last")
    else:
        self.text_area.tag_add("p", "sel.first", "sel.last")
        self.text_area.tag_config("p", background="green", foreground="white")
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit about what you have tried. Can you link the similar question? "I tried to use the method dump() and failed" explain why it does not work for you and if got an error, please provide the full error message along with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `dump` is the proper way to get all of the contents of the widget including the tags. Getting text and tags is specifically what `dump` was designed to do.